# I want to pick the file name from event logs using python lamda function

Tags: aws-lambda

want to get file name from cloud watch log. which I've uploaded in s3 bucket. But it gives me Key error 'Records' I check in logs as well. Everytning in my code is according to logs event.
**here is my code**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     s3 = boto3.client('s3')
     if event:
        print("Event:", event)
        for Records in event["Records"]:
            file_obj = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
            print("FileObj", file_obj)
        filename = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
        print("Filename:", filename)
        fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket = "prcbucket", key=filename)
        print("FileObj", fileObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should be sufficient to retrieve the key

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print key
```